# Android: Random Generation in a Networked Situation (Multiplayer)

Tags: java, android, random, google-play-games, multiplayer

I wrote a class that, given a seed and difficulty, will return a playing field to my game. The generation is consistent (no matter what, the same seed & difficulty level will always result in the same play field). As far as I know all android devices use Java 1.6 so here goes my question(s):

Is it safe to send only the seed and difficulty to other devices in a multiplayer environment?

Do I need to worry about when Google updates Java version level form 1.6? or will they likely update all android devices to that version level (I am assuming the Random class will have been changed)? And if not what would be a good way to detect if Random class is different?

Rephrased, what precautionary measures should be in place to ensure that the class java.util.Random, which my field generation class uses heavily, will result in the same play field for every device? Or, alternatively, would it be more wise to consider sending all play field data to the non-hosting device(s)?

I could probably accomplish the latter with a reliable message with size of:

```
byte[ROWS * COLUMNS]
```

In advance, I appreciate any guidance/suggestions in this matter. This is a difficult issue to search for so some links for future views may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options here, but I guess I was hoping for some magic JVM property defining the java.util.Random class revision version.

First option is to check the java version and compare it against the other device's version. If they are the same it is safe (as far as I know) to assume that the Random class is the same and thus the seed and difficulty can be sent. If, however, they are different you either send all the data or check the documentation/version release notes yourself to see when the Random class was changed and then determine if all the data should be sent based on previously acquired java version identifier.

The second option is to simply always send all the data. Which is what I will personally be doing.

If you're not as lucky as I and your data exceeds the value of Multiplayer.MAX_RELIABLE_MESSAGE_LEN (in bytes) you may have to break the data into multiple messages which could get ugly but is entirely doable.